# Broken snap, unable to run

Tags: snap

Spotify shows as broken in the snap list

```
$ snap list
Name     Version  Rev   Tracking  Publisher     Notes
core     16-2.39  6964  stable    canonical✓    core
hiri     1.4.0.5  56    stable    hiri✓         -
postman           81    stable    postman-inc✓  broken
spotify           35    stable    spotify✓      broken
```

I tried:

```
snap refresh spotify --edge
snap restart spotify
snap run spotify
```

How can I solve and be able to run spotify again.

Comment: uninstall and reinstall could do the trick. you can perform those operations from the software center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply open up the Software center and uninstall and reinstall it.